# Templates not found in Flask Blueprint

Tags: python, flask

I'm working on an app using Blueprints and I followed the documentation quickstart on Blueprints, but still have a 404 on my templates.

I got an `admin` blueprint looking like that:

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template

admin = Blueprint('admin', __name__, template_folder='templates')

@admin.route('/')
def admin_index():
    return render_template('admin/index.html.jinja2')
```

As described in the doc, my template is in /myapp/admin/templates/index.html.jinja2+

I register the blueprint in my app `__init__.py` file:

```
from flask import Flask
from . import config
from admin import admin

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(config.DevelopmentConfig)

# register my blueprint
app.register_blueprint(admin, url_prefix='/admin/')
```

If anyone has an idea about a mistake I could have done, please tell me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not accurate about [docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/blueprints/#templates). Your templates shoud be in

```
myapp/admin/templates/admin/index.html.jinja2
```

Note `admin` folder in `templates`.

Comment: Thanks for your help ! You're right, i didn't understood the `admin` level inside the template folder was required. Thanks again